# how to store nested list as a value of dictionary in python

Tags: python-2.7

I am novice in python. I have a project to implement the Dijkstra algorithm. The structure of the graph looks like as follows:

```
G = {n1: [[n2, weight], [n3, weight]],n2: [[n1, weight], [n4, weight]],n3: [[n1, weight]],n4: [[n2, weight]]}
```

How can I make structure for G, node, edge and their relationships?

Comment: What exactly do you want? You want a `key` in a dictionary with a list as `value` (as you have in the example)?

Comment: I want node as a dictionary key and value is adjacent nodes that means edge with weight.

Answer (score 0):

```
G = {n1: [[n2, weight], [n3, weight]],n2: [[n1, weight], [n4, weight]],n3: [[n1, weight]],n4: [[n2, weight]]}

print type(G) # will return a dict

print G.keys() # n1, n2, n3, n4.

print G.values() # will get a list, so, for example, to have [n2, weight]

G[n1][0] # and to have only n2:

G[n1][0][0]
```

Dont forget to you `print type(something)` to know how to deal with it.